# Not able to get Publishing Status through PublishManager

Tags: publishing, publishing-service

I am using Publishing Service and tried to implement the Publish Manager API to retrieve Publish Status, but once the publishing is completed (successfully or unsuccessfully) the PublishManager.GetStatus(handle) returns **null**.

So, I am not able to actually get the  exact status of publishing once its completed.

Below is the code that I tried to implement:

```
var handle = PublishManager.PublishItem(item, new[] { _webDb }, _webDb.Languages, true, false);

if (handle != null)
{
  var publishStatus = PublishManager.GetStatus(handle);
  if (publishStatus != null)
  {
    while (!publishStatus.IsDone)
    {
      Thread.Sleep(30000);
      publishStatus = PublishManager.GetStatus(handle);
    }

     // Log the publishing status once its finished
     Logger.Info("Publish Status: " + publishStatus.State);
     Logger.Info("Publish Status : IsDone: " + publishStatus.IsDone);
     Logger.Info("Publish Status : IsExpired: " + publishStatus.Expired);
     Logger.Info("Publish Status : IsFailed: " + publishStatus.Failed);                            
    }
}
```

Also I tried to implement below, but this also returns Publish Status as null

```
var handle = PublishManager.PublishItem(sitemapRoot, new[] { _webDb }, _webDb.Languages, true, false);
PublishManager.WaitFor(handle);

var publishStatus = PublishManager.GetStatus(handle);
```

Could there be any other way by which we can get the Publishing Status to know whether it was a success or failure?

Comment: You can take a look at at the various APIs from the publishing dialog to figure out how to report the various publishing status and results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the Publishing Service you can use the values that are shown on the Dashboard by accessing `/sitecore/client/Applications/Publishing/Dashboard`:

[image]

If you look at the Network tab you will see that it is doing a call to the API `/sitecore/api/ssc/publishing/jobs/%7B00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000%7D/All?sourceDatabase=master`. This basically retrieves a JSON with all the Jobs aswell as their statuses. The first part of the JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "Messages": [],
  "Active": [],
  "Queued": [],
  "Recent": [
    {
      "ManifestIdList": [
        "39cbd98d-7abd-4c35-b152-6c18d7a81532"
      ],
      "Type": {
        "DisplayName": "Single Item"
      },
      "TypeDisplayName": "Item publish",
      "ItemId": "{6bfa19da-4596-473d-8c78-0411cfd83799}",
      "SourceDatabase": "master",
      "ItemName": "CommonName6bfa19da-4596-473d-8c78-0411cfd83799",
      "RequestedBy": "sitecore\\admin",
      "Status": "Completed",
      "StatusMessage": "OK",
      "Languages": [
        {
          "Code": "en",
          "DisplayName": "English"
        }
      ],
```

You would use the `"Status": "Completed"` in your code to verify if the Job finished successfully. The same would apply to see if the Job is in Active, Queued or Recent.